# Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://xxxxx.xxx:7072/.well-known/openid-configuration'

Tags: ssl, .net-core, identityserver4

Всем доброго времени суток. 
Уже который день бьюсь с одной проблемой. 
1) Есть IDS 
2) Есть API 
3) Есть Nginx

При обращении API к IDS вываливается ошибка

> Connection id "0HLRTUMAJDSKM", Request id "0HLRTUMAJDSKM:00000001": An
>   unhandled exception was thrown by the application. дек 11 05:00:33
>   xxx-srv-xxxxxx dotnet-example[31709]:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain
>   configuration from:
>   'https://xxxxx.xxx:7072/.well-known/openid-configuration'. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from:
>   'https://xxxxx.xxx:7072/.well-known/openid-configuration'. --->
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be
>   established, see inner exception. --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Я так понимаю что проблема на стороне net core. Что он не может валидировать сертификат с которым прилетает запрос.

Но я не могу понять, как исправить эту ситуацию.
Может быть кто то сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: `The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure` Судя по всему у вас проблема в сертификате на стороне сервера. Вы используете валидный сертификат или самоподписный?

Comment: Есть валидный сертификат. Этот сертификат используется в настройках IDS. Мне кажется надо как то сказать API чтоб он понимал этот сертификат.

Comment: Вот история один в один с моей: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029889/how-to-fix-unable-to-obtian-configuration-from-https-localhost5001-wel-kno   Может быть это натолкнет на мысли кого нибудь.

Comment: 1) Если открыть в браузере эту ссылку ругается на сертификат? 2) Про валидность сертификата я имел в виду используется ли сертификат подписанный вышестоящим центром сертификации (например LetsEncrypt) и выписан ли он на тот же домен на который обращаетесь?

Comment: 3) Попробовать костыльный способ с игнорированием валидности сертификата (Гугл -> "net core ignore certificate validation")

Comment: 1) Нет не ругается 2) Да сертификат подписанный как надо 3) попробую отпишусь.

Comment: Что я еще заметил если обратиться к API через браузер, при этом наблюдал Fiddler ом,  то API возвращает данные как надо. Но стоит добавить в заголовок Токен, сразу натыкаемся на вышеобозначенную ошибку.  Пока что не понимаю как это связано.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось дело было в сертификате. Сертификат был подписан внутренним центром сертификации, а внешние ничего о нём не знали. 
Браузер говорил что сертификат валидный, сервисы же не могли подтвердить его валидность. 
Нарушалась цепочка сертификатов. 
После того как добавили по настоящему валидный сертификат всё заработало в штатном режиме.

Comment: О чем я и говорил. Если используете самоподписные сертификаты, то нужно добавлять корневой сертификат на все машины где используются эти сертификаты(сервер плюс все клиенты). Но во времена с бесплатными сертификатами (LetsEncrypt) проще сделать нормальный валидный сертификат.